# PC won't boot to windows

Tags: laptop

Just last night after I used my laptop, I pressed the power button which was suppose to hibernate but the display went off and the lights on the mother board (power button light,  caps lock light,  wifi light, and some other indicator light)  were still on for about 15 min. So,  I decided to press the power button down for about 7 secs then it died. So I tried to power it on again and properly hibernate it,  Then that is when started. Its restarts after bios post wait about 2-3 secs then restart again,  it kept on doing that repeatedly. I tried defaulting the bios but still the same. So I'm still on it since. 
Any help would really be appreciated. 
Forgive my English its crappy 
Model : HP Compaq nc8230

Comment: This might be a question better posed to superuser; you may get replies here but superuser is more likely to have people who know what to do, I think.

Comment: On such an old laptop (it's a model introduced in 2005) my first guess would be a problem with the BIOS backup battery. If there is a way to easily remove that battery, try that and see if that helps.

Comment: From the description "I tried defaulting the bios" which I think means you can successfully open the BIOS and attempt to choose an OS.  It's worth while trying to boot from a Lubuntu DVD or similar.  Creating a Lubuntu DVD will require a second PC with a burner, and some research.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for your time and answers... I figured it out. I removed the hard drive, I turned it on after  the Post it notified me there was a missing HDD or no operating system.  Then I gave the theory I had on my head a try.  I inserted a windows XP CD into the DVD drive and went through the normal installation process and it went smooth.  To summarize it all,  I installed an XP on it. After that,  I installed windows 7 back on it, it works fine now.. I think the problem was from Os.Now Its up and running again.  Thank you all.